# Receive each week the number of posts published

Tags: posts, email

I'm trying to create an email alert every monday at midnight that will send the number of posts published the past week on the site.

I created 2 variables: `$post_published_to_date` which is the total count of the posts on the site (I assumed here that the site was just created to there aren't any posts yet) and `$published_posts` which is the number of posts published during the past week.

I used `date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon' && $timestamp = strtotime('midnight')`in the `if` statement to find out if it's monday at midnight. If it is, an email is sent to the admin with the number of posts published.

I'm not sure is setting  `$published_posts` to 0 at the end will work well, and I'm afraid `$post_published_to_date` will be reset to 0 each time. I'm beginning in Php so I'm not really sure here.

```
 <?php
    $post_published_to_date = 0;
    $published_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;

    if(date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon' && $timestamp = strtotime('midnight')) { 
    $post_published_to_date = $post_published_to_date + $published_posts;


    add_action( 'publish_post', 'number_of_posts_published', 10 ,2 );
    function number_of_posts_published( $ID, $post, $published_posts; ) {
        if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type)
            return;

        $to = 'admin@mysite.com'
        $subject = 'Number of posts last week';
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html' );
        $message = '<h3> Hello ! </h3> <p>  

        Last week, $published_posts posts were published on your site. ';


        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, 'Content-Type: text/html' ); 
    }


    $published_posts = 0; 
    }

    ?>
```

Would this work as expected ? Would you advise any modification that are better practices ?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Why not get a count from a query that only pulls posts published within the past 7 days?

Comment: That's probably a very good idea but I don't know how to do this ... Would you have a few minutes to help me out ? Thanks for your answer and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic use for WP_Query that returns an object containing all posts for the current week as `$query`.  The last line echos the property `found_posts', which provides the count for the week query.

```
    $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year' => date( 'Y' ),
                'week' => date( 'W' ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    echo $query->found_posts;
```

For your purposes, I do not know if the week is based on an empirical calendar or if this is based on your site's Settings > General > date settings.

With a little testing you should be able to produce reliable results for your email each week.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters